# Failed with Python 2.7.x installation on Windows 10 machine for npm dependency

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-2.7, npm

I am trying to install Python 2.7.x versions (multiple) on my Windows 10 laptop to fix npm Python dependency error. But unfortunately i am getting the following error:

> The system cannot find the device or file specified.

[image]

How do I resolve this issue. My system is Windows 10 64 bit laptop.